# Regular expression to remove specific characters from string

Tags: regex

I have a string from which I need to remove some characters. The string will be something like this:

```
examplestring.o.pdf
```

I need to remove the `.o`.

The first part, `examplestring`, will vary in length.

`.o` will always be in the same position.

Can anyone help me with a regular expression to remove the `.o` so it ends up being `examplestring.pdf`?

Comment: You said "the first part, 'examplestring', will vary in length," and ".o will always be in the same position." Could you explain what you mean by "same position?" Maybe you're counting the distance from the end of the string?

Comment: Also, what language are you programming in? Is the string you want to remove always ".o" or does it vary? And where's your code so far?

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that you have two parts in your string: the first part can vary and the 2nd part that ends with `.o.pdf`.

You can use a regex with a positive lookahead to replace with empty string

```
\.o(?=\.pdf)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/8cDWUu/2)**

You can also replace the literal string `.o.` by `.`, and if you want to use a regex then you can escape the wildcards to `\.o\.`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to remove the ".o" from your string, then concatenate the two capture groups.

```
(\w+)\.o(.pdf)
```

Comment: The period before the `o` would capture any character. If the OP wants to specifically capture the period then it would need escaping like `\.`

Comment: do you know that, your pattern cannot handle `example string.o.pdf` with a single space